# How to multiply each elements in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, multiplication

I want to multiply each element in my list by 2, but I got ['123123', '456456', '789789'] instead of [246, 912, 1578].

Here's my code

```
list = ['123', '456', '789']
my_new_list = []
for i in list:
    my_new_list.append(i*2)

print (my_new_list)
```

what should i change or add to the code to get [246, 912, 1578]?

Comment: Turn your list into numbers instead of strings

Comment: `list = list(map(int, list))` or `list = [int(x) for x in list]` to do what @rdas said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are multiplying strings. Instead multiply integers.

```
list = ['123', '456', '789']
my_new_list = []
for i in list:
    my_new_list.append(int(i)*2)

print (my_new_list)
```

Or just make every number in list an integer.
Also here is a list comprehension version of your code

```
list = ['123', '456', '789']
my_new_list = [int(i)*2 for i in list]
```

List Comprehension you should look into it. [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)